# JAVA - Using same POJO but with less fields (without jackson)

Tags: java, object, pojo

I have a POJO used by an existing endpoint, this endpoint responds with all fields present in the POJO.
But I'm creating a new enpoint which should respond only some of the fields of the same POJO.
I want to avoid copying the same POJO file and deleting the parameters I don't need, is there a way to do this?

This is the POJO:

```java
public class AgentChatStatus {

  private UUID activeChat;
  private List<AgentChat> chatRequests; //Object with less params on new endpoint
  private List<AgentChat> chatsOnHold; //Object with less params on new endpoint
  private Collection<Agent> agents;
  private int totalChatRequests;
  private int totalChatsOnHold;
  private Preferences.AgentConsoleConfig config;
// ...
}
```

```
public class AgentChat implements Payload {
  private UUID id;
  private String queueId;
```

Lets say I only need to show "Id" in endpoint 2 but id and  queueId in endpoint1.
I work with spring btw.
Thanks!

Comment: Parameters? Did you field fields? Are you talking about serializing your objects into JSON? Why without Jackson - what do you use then?

Comment: We also need to see how this class is returned by your app. What framework you using, you don't say at all?

Comment: yes I mean fields, wihout jackson because I need one endpoint to respond with all fields, the other endpoind only with a few.

Comment: using spring in my app

Comment: But are you using Jackson? Because Jackson can help with this.

Comment: yes, I am using jackson currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jackson you can take advantage of JSON Views. The first thing is to create the Views as follows:

```java
public class Views {
    public static class ViewEndpoint2 { // The name can be whatever you want
    }

    public static class ViewEndpoint1 extends ViewEndpoint2 {
    }
}
```

Then you need to annotate the properties in your POJO with `@JsonView` so that you tell Jackson in which views such properties should be visible:

```java
public class AgentChatStatus {

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private UUID activeChat;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private List<AgentChat> chatRequests;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private List<AgentChat> chatsOnHold;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private Collection<Agent> agents;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private int totalChatRequests;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private int totalChatsOnHold;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private Preferences.AgentConsoleConfig config;

}
```

```java
public class AgentChat implements Payload {
  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
  private UUID id;

  @JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint1.class)
  private String queueId;
}
```

Finally, you need to annotate the endpoints with the corresponding view:

```java
@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint1.class)
@RequestMapping("your-old-enpoint")
public void yourOldEndpoint() {
    (...)
}

@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)
@RequestMapping("your-new-enpoint")
public void yourNewEndpoint() {
    (...)
}
```

`@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint1.class)` basically means all properties in `AgentChatStatus` and `AgentChat` and `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)` means only some of them (the ones annotated with `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)`).

You can read more about this at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation.

Comment: this is what a need, thank you! I will implement this today and tell the feed back here.

Comment: Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: what about chatRequests and chatsOnHold properties, I also need to show only some properties depending on the endpoint, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you just need to apply the same logic to those classes. If you share them and tell us which properties you want to be excluded in the second endpoint I could updated my answer.

Comment: Done, please check my updated answer ;)

Comment: excellent, implementing as we speak, I'll comment the feedback, this is exactly what i needed, thanks

Comment: Can I do this, If I need a propertie to be shown on both endpoints: @JsonView({Views.ViewEndpoint2.class, Views.ViewEndpoint1.class}) ? @João Dias

Comment: No need. `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)` will show it on both, because `ViewEndpoint1` extends `ViewEndpoint2`.

Comment: Works perfectly, just as a little note: all properties must be annotated or it wont work at all. Thanks, this was exactly what I needed

Comment: Awesome! Yup, all need to be annotated, sorry for missing that relevant info.

Comment: Now I have a new challenge, I need ViewEndpoint2 to show some parameters, now Im creating new ones. But these new ones (and only the new ones) cannot be shown on ViewEndpoint1. I have been thinking a lot, no ideas yet. Is it possible?

Comment: Try creating a `public static class ViewEndpoint3 extends ViewEndpoint2`. Replace `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint2.class)` with `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint3.class)` in the controller method that defines the endpoint. Finally, annotate those new parameters with `@JsonView(Views.ViewEndpoint3.class)`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Works 100% perfect, in fact my code is ready, thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding ;)

Comment: Is there any way to not allow the ViewEndpoint3 fields to appear on non annotated endpoints? I have thousand of endpoints and I dont want to put a annotation on them

Comment: Not that I am aware of, unfortunatelly.